# Any reason to use standard value-wrapper types from google.protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers

After the addition of `optional` keyword to protobuf 3, which allows explicit presence tracking of scalar fields, are there any reasons to use value-wrapper types from google.protobuf, like [BoolValue](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#bool-value) or [DoubleValue](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#double-value) etc? Is there any other usage for those except presence tracking?

Answer (score 1):

When you need to pack primitive types into `google::protobuf::Any`, you have to use these wrappers. `Any` can only work with message type, not primitive type.

```
// C++ code:

DoubleValue b;
b.set_value(2.3);

Any any;
any.PackFrom(b);   // You cannot pack from a double

DoubleValue bb;
any.UnpackTo(&bb);  // you cannot unpack to a double

cout << bb.value() << endl;
```